# How well supported is a ThinkPad X121e?

Tags: thinkpad, lenovo

I am planning to invest in a LENOVO ThinkPad X121e (NWS5YGE 30515YG) which does not have a preinstalled os. ([shop's site](http://www.uni-notebooks.de/Single-Ansicht.140.0.html?&no_cache=1&tt_products%5BbackPID%5D=2593&tt_products%5Bproduct%5D=17337&cHash=847d3e914c2dc99f66c1526dbe5f0a34), sry it is in german)

What I want to know is if the TP x121e is fully supported, and yes what configurations I might have to use.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself am using a Lenovo Thinkpad but not the same model [ T61p ] and everything works absolutely fine, right out of the box.

Now, specs are not the same at all but I do believe the x121e should work just fine. The only thing I am worried about is the WiFi adaptor. You should go on Lenovo's website to see the exact model of the WiFi card and check the compatibility with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Ubuntu Friendly](http://friendly.ubuntu.com/11.10/LENOVO/ThinkPad%20X121e/A%3aFep%3aKHe%3aBEG%3aCQE%3aB9ip%3aIc8%3aBHs%3aIdD%3aBHs/status/) (beta) the core components of the laptop including the ATI graphics and Realtek wireless are 100% compatible with Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1):

This laptop is HORRIBLY Noisy. I have the i3 version. The CPU fan is really noisy although, I managed to control it using thinkfan. It still is very very noisy. It starts
very loudly, and makes the internal microphone captures its noise.
If  you are on the roads and you need to make a VOIP call this is really impossible to talk with the internal speaker (I think if Lenovo people put the speaker the other side of the case, it would have been less problematic).
Everything else works with Ubuntu, but I am still very sorry I bought that laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64 on an Lenovo x121E with Intel Cpu without any hardware/driver problems.

Comment: Hi & welcome! Can you add configuration? Asker says *What I want to know is if the TP x121e is fully supported, and yes what configurations I might have to use.*

Comment: Thanks, the configuration is: Intel Core i3-2357M, Intel HD Graphics 3000

Comment: - Setup BIOS:  Menu "Startup"
  - UEFI/Legacy Boot: both  (UEFI *and* Legacy)
  - UEFI/Legacy Boot Priority: "Legacy first" (important!)
  You have to setup BIOS before (!) installation.
  Otherwise you encounter "Grub error, invalid arch independent ELF magic" or "No operating system"
- Setup BIOS: Menu "USB"
  - USB UEFI BIOS Support may be "Enabled" for that You can install Ubuntu from an bootable USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 on a ThnkPad X100e, which has:
-AMD® Athlon™ Neo Single Core MV-40 (1.6 GHz), 512KB L2 cache 
-ATI Radeon HD 3200 graphics, M780G 
-250 GB (5400 rpm) 
-6 cell: 2.6 Ah, 10.8 V 
-11.6" HD, 1366 x 768 resolution
-Camera on top of screen, 0.3-megapixel

I did not install any of the proprietary graphics drivers.  Everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model (x121e) and Ubuntu 11.10 works very well on it except this very annoying [burp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85165/after-suspend-hibernate-fn-keys-function-is-inverted-thinkpad-x121e). But [it seems to be the same under some other OS](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/X121e-FN-Standby-Bug/td-p/533431). It seems it is considered a BIOS bug. Except that, the support of 11.10 to this cute gadget is almost perfect. All the hardware is well supported. I did not have any problem with the WIFI in Ubuntu 11.10. I did not have to install any additional drivers manually. Had a bit problem with skype concerning the audio in/out.

Then I upgraded to 12.04. Now I can not showdown or restart x121e from the menu (the system only logs me out). Have to use command line to shut it down.

Answer (score 0):

On 12.10 i had to solve two issues:

1. black screen after resume. Solved by installing laptop-mode-tools package
2. booting into black screen. Solved by adding the following line into `/etc/default/grub`:

   ```
   GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="1366x768"
   ```

Everything else works out of the box.