# After suspend/hibernate Fn keys function is inverted ThinkPad X121e

Tags: 11.10, thinkpad

On my ThinkPad X121e running Ubuntu 11.10 I have a problem with the Fn key after the laptop went to suspension mode or hibernate (does not matter which one, occurs with both).

After resuming from such modes the working of the Fn key is inverted, i.e. normally you would use Fn+F5 to toggle the radios (Bluetooth and WLAN), but after the suspension hitting just F5 toggles it, while you have to press Fn+F5 to get the normal "F5" event.

Also if you swap the Fn and Ctrl key in the EFI settings it works normally until suspension or hibernate was used, then the key suddenly start to get their orignal functionality until you reboot.

Has somebody some advise how to solve this, this behaviour is very distracting since you can't use suspend and hibernate any more (or you have to think twice every time before hitting the affected keys).

**Update:**
I have been in contact with the Lenovo support. Both a change of the keyboard module and a attempt to fix it in their repair centre have been unsuccessful. I returned the device to Lenovo and got my money back. It seems this (among others) is a persistent problem with this model series. I got a different device from another company now.

Comment: I have the same problem on X121e. Upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 does not solve the problem.

Comment: Does this happens with latest stable version?

Comment: After two repair attempts by the Lenovo Service I returned the device and got my money back. I assume it does, since these sersies seems very bugged (heared that from others as well) and Lenovo did not seem to have a clue/interest in fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is this thread but they didn't find a solution either: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/X121e-FN-Standby-Bug/td-p/533431